# Mounting NTFS in Linux vs. mounting EXT4 in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, mount

Is there any particular reason, why modern Linux based OSes are able to create and mount NTFS natively, while Windows just straight-up doesn't support "Linux-filesystems" like ext2/3/4 and requires extra software to do so?

Comment: All that can be said is that Microsoft has not chosen to have Windows support Linux filesystems. Anything beyond that is speculation and opinion.

Comment: the same reason why macOS doesn't supported ext4, ZFS, Btrfs... natively, and why Linux doesn't supported APFS or HFS+ natively, or even ZFS sometime ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any particular reason, why Linux based OSes are able to create and mount NTFS natively, while Windows just straight-up doesn't support EXT4 for example and requires extra software to do so?

One big difference is that Windows is developed by a single company prioritizing its tasks and interests, and Ext4 support isn't among them or is very low. Meanwhile Linux-based systems are collections of various independent projects (it's in the name: a *distribution*) – Ubuntu doesn't have to spend its own resources on developing software that someone has already written.

So the NTFS-3g driver for Linux wasn't developed specifically as a distribution feature, but rather as a third-party project that most distributions could simply decide to include as an in-box component later. In other words, **it is "extra software."**

(Or at least, it could be called that until earlier this year, when *another* NTFS driver called "ntfs3" was contributed to directly become part of the Linux kernel – unlike NTFS-3g, which was an external program the entire time.)

There are similar filesystem driver projects for Windows, too – ext2IFS, ext4fsd, Paragon ExtFS, WinBtrfs – but the bar for a third-party product to be included with Windows is generally *much* higher. (Ongoing maintenance is a concern; past such products mostly were "license version X.Y and never update it anymore" kind of deals. Even if it's an open-source project, a filesystem driver is not something you can import and forget – Microsoft would need to allocate time and effort to maintaining it, which is probably as much as writing it in the first place.)

Linux itself is the biggest exception to that (being included in WSL2), likely in part because Microsoft already employs quite a few Linux developers anyway – and in fact, Windows [can now (indirectly) mount Ext4 filesystems](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/) by relying on the Ext4 drivers that are part of the WSL2 Linux kernel.

Comment: Yet Microsoft chose to include OpenSSH into Windows as a "feature", both server and client. I think, there was quite a big demand for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant demand for Ext4 FS support in Windows, so they don't bother. Compare this with OpenSSH recently added into Windows as a feature, both client and server.

Ext4 is not a single FS which is not supported in Windows — it only supports a tiny fraction of them: FAT, NTFS, ISO9660, UDF, and... that's all, I think. So, for example, why don't you ask why it doesn't have a support for HFS+ and XFS? What's about ZFS support? What about other file systems, like UFS, VxFS and so on? Why so focused on Ext4?

Also, it is not very useful just to have the support for the file system. It is often deployed on LVM, so you'd better support LVM too (Linux supports Windows's LDM, by the way). Add software RAID. Add LUKS. Add caching (bcache and so on). That is much work, and for what purpose? Who would use this support?

I'm a very long time Linux user (since 1999) and system administrator. I don't think the NTFS support is so required in the Linux for an average user, and it's rather special and niche thing. For removable storage, there is exFAT; for the dual boot... I doubt the dual boot is very useful thing itself, most "dualbooters" I knew really didn't boot into "other" system much; even if you are going to use one system for work and other for gaming, why there could be a need for them to access each other files? So I presume many advanced Windows users just feel the same about Ext4 support — it's no use. So well, why Microsoft should bother to include its support?

Comment: there's no reason for MS to spend effort writing an ext4 driver for Windows. That's why when they have the real Linux kernel in WSL2 they simply utilize that kernel to mount ext4 partitions on Windows

Comment: I doubt it was done to support Ext4 file system. That came as the nice free addition.